# Gradient Circle with Multiple Colours at multiple Locations in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I need a gradient circle with 4 colours at 4 locations in Android.I have been searching for it google but found none.I got solution for only 3 colours with different opacities.I will give my colour specifications.Please help me with xml solution which will work in **Android Studio**

Color Code:
Gradient Type:Radial
Shape:Circle
Location:100% Color:#f29265 Alpha:100%
Location:87% Color:#f29265 Alpha:100%
Location:45% Color:#f76394 Alpha:100%
Location:0% Color:#f76394 Alpha:100%

```
        <gradient
            android:gradientRadius="70dp"
            android:centerX="50%"
            android:centerY="50%"
            android:centerColor="#73F76394"
            android:startColor="#00F76394"
            android:endColor="#F92965"
            android:type="radial"
            />
```

Comment: create the images and use them

Comment: I need to do some animations as well with the circles.So I need to work with drawable circles only

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a gradient with more than 3 colors in android.

Comment: This should be stated as a comment instead of an answer.